# Navigator handles in Highstock can't be dragged

Tags: highcharts

I'm new to Highstock and I was playing with the samples, but I saw that the navigator isn't working in any of them, i.e. https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume (tested in FF and Chrome on W10).

I guess the navigator allows to modify the windows size of the chart, zomming in and out over the data. They show the left-right arrows on mouse hover but they can't be dragged.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I checked this on chrome on w10 and it works correctly. Can you give more details about browsers version?

Comment: It doesn't work on:
Firefox 52.0.1 (32-bit) / 
Chrome 56.0.2924.87.

It works on Edge (I can't find where is the version)

Comment: Chrome was just updated to Version 57.0.2987.110 and it doesn't work either.